# scrape the particular div section from table

Tags: python, web-scraping

In this 'td' section there are many div section without any name, i want the data of particular div section, how to do that i try with following code but it gives the many output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/person.asp?personId=45794107&privcapId=8032555&previousCapId=12437591&previousTitle=Pawan%20Hans%20Limited"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

data = []

for table in soup.findAll('table'):
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        for col in row.findAll('td'):
            #print(col.findAll('div'))
            data.append(col.get_text())
print(data)
```

I want the following output:

```
2017-Present
Independent Director
Air India Limited
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/person.asp?personId=45794107&privcapId=8032555&previousCapId=12437591&previousTitle=Pawan%20Hans%20Limited"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

data = []

table = soup.find_all('table', cellpadding="0")[2]
divs = table.find_all('div')[1:4]

for div in divs:
    print div.get_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could achieve the same without using hardcoded index:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/person.asp?personId=45794107&privcapId=8032555&previousCapId=12437591&previousTitle=Pawan%20Hans%20Limited"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
for items in soup.find_all(class_="sectionTitle"):
    if "Board Members" in items.text:
        item = items.find_next_sibling()
        presence = items.find_next_sibling().text
        position = item.find_next("div")
        company = item.find_next("a")
        print("{}\n{}\n{}".format(presence,position.text,company.text))
```

Output:

```
2017-Present
Independent Director
Air India Limited
```